# urlrewriting.net not accepting arabic query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, arabic

i am going crazy, i have tried everything, urlencode, html encode, but urlrewriting.net is reading Arabic querystring as  ?? charecters

totally appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long tedious trials My advise to anyone who is using URL Rewriting with IIS 7 in integrated mode, stop wasting your time and either use MVC routing or forget about Arabic Strings in URL

Answer (score 3):

If you have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed, I'd recommend you to switch to `System.Web.Routing` instead of the UrlRewriting.net library. I've recently switched from UrlRewriting.net to `System.Web.Routing` myself and routing is so much better thought out and better integrated with the ASP.NET pipeline.

If you have the opportunity to switch, I'd recommend it. If not, please post your UrlRewriting.net configuration file so we can tweak the regular expressions that apparently aren't working. Please post some examples of URIs that don't work too.

Also, what's the values defined in the `web.config` section:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8"
                 responseEncoding="utf-8"
                 fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

Like in the above example, use UTF-8. Also be sure to encode the characters as UTF-8 in the URI.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run the IIS 7 application in "Classic Mode" (might require installation to be an available option)?

Comment: it works in Classic mode, 
i have tried every URL Rewriting method out there commercial and free and i have ended using MVC and ditching the whole web forms model, now everything works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this , it is faster .. and problems free .

"~/News/2008/10/10/newsid/تجربة.aspx"
where newsid is the ID of your article .

Get your title from the database : 'select * from news where id = ' & newsid
It is much faster than : "select *  from news where title='"& title &"'"

Comment: thanks alot man for the great tip,
but seriously i have forgot about web forms and with MVC everything is so smooth

Answer (score 0):

it seems that i have solved the problem by making sure that both pages, the one that contains the link and the one to parse the query string have UTF-8 Encoding

but now i got another problem
Firefox is displaying the hyper link and the link in address bar correctly
but in IE6 and Ie 7 it is like this

```
mysite/News/2008/10/10/%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A9.aspx
```

even though IE 6 and 7 are parsing the link fine, but this is ugly, what is the solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: man you wont believe it, i have found the problem it is so strange, it is with IIS 7 Integrated Mode, 
try to launch your page from visual studio Dev server and Unicode characters will be parsed just fine, but if you launch the page from IIS 7 it will give you the ???? characters.

hope some body will shade some light here